# how to stop a youtube link to load other videos in gmail template? Is javascript or jquery useful in this case?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, email, youtube

i am putting a youtube link into `gmail template`, when i add this template to gmail body other related you tube videos also getting loading dynamically.how to stop them. 
My link looks like this

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5uqzvPGybUk?rel=0" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.isevabiz.com/email_201707/link2.png" height="100px" style="border:2px solid #CCDD77"><br/>AD Film 02</a>
```

this link is loading other youtube videos in gmail when sending mail using `java mail api` how to stop them.
can we use `javascript` or `jquery`?

here is the screen shot

[image]

in this 1 and 2 are the youtube links and circled videos are got loaded dynamically. how to stop them loading dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For security reasons, you can't run javascript in an email, at least at gmail.

Please have a look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Templates.2C_scripts_and_programming_languages). It tells you what email client allows js and what doesn't.

Comment: then how to stop dynamic loading , am using java smtp mail api to send that template can we do it in java?

Comment: @bharath by saying "dynamic loading" do you mean the preview image generated at the bottom of the email?

Comment: let me add screen shot please look at screenshot link

Comment: @bharath I'm afraid there is no solution for that, given that it is a function of Gmail to do it. It may or may not show the thumbnail depending on what client is the receiver using. Currently, there is no way to stop gmail from doing that.

Comment: @bharath you can try to use shortlinks to replace the youtube link, try goo.gl or bit.ly 
it's a "passive" way to solve that